# How does Return types makes a difference in case of Method overloading?

Tags: java

In case of method overloading, if there are two methods used in same class with same number of variables, with different data-types and with different Return Types, while calling the method, if we pass only two values, then which method gets executed and if it does not get executed, what error we will get?

Comment: It is hard to know exactly what you know from that quite abstract description. Could you add a very short example?

Comment: A tiny bit of code would be better to get

Comment: the method to be executed depends on the types of variables that  you pass in method invocation

Comment: I suggest you try this out with a test code to find out how it behaves and then come back with a question asking for a reason.

Comment: Voting to close because this is a rhetorical question in that it is easily answered by simply *trying it*.

Answer (score 5):

Return type is ignored when deciding which method to call. Only the argument types are taken into account. See [JLS #8.4.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9).